# How can I match an <a> tag based on the text that precedes it?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        I do not want this link here <a href="blah">link text</a>
        But I want this one here <a href="blah blah">more link text</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get only the second `<a>` tag and am using the following:

```
//*[contains(.,"But I want this one here ")]/a
```

This returns

```
<a href="blah">link text</a>
<a href="blah blah">more link text</a>
```

I would like just

```
<a href="blah blah">more link text</a>
```

Comment: So are you looking for the element that follows the text `I want this one here` or is it just the 2nd link?

Comment: I want the element that follows the text `But I want this one here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//text()[normalize-space()="But I want this one here"]/following-sibling::*[1]
```

will select the element immediately following `"But I want this one here"`,

```
<a href="blah blah">more link text</a>
```

as requested.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get the `href` attribute value of the following `<a>` is

```
//text()[contains(.,"But I want this one here ")]/following-sibling::a/@href
```

Its output is

```
blah blah
```

To only retrieve the element node, omit the `/@href`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
//*[contains(following-sibling::text()[1],"But I want this one here")]/following-sibling::a
```